# Where is Leaflet JS object that holds all "features" on US map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working with the [Leaflet US map example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) and I have a situation where I need to have one state already highlighted when the map page loads.

The highlight code is fairly straightforward (this is directly from the [map example code](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) and works fine):

```
function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
    });

    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) { layer.bringToFront(); }
}
```

My challenge is that this code is called when the user rolls over a state-- which generates a mouseover event, and then that event (e) is passed to the function, and the function can use the details in the event to figure out which state the user is pointing to. When the page LOADS, however, there is no event per se. I don't know where those states are being stored. Where/what is the JS object that holds all the states?

I am guessing my code will be eventually be something like...

```
// on page load, highlight the active state
var activeState = 'Arizona';

// loop through each state and find the one where 
// feature.properties.name == activeState
// ...???...

// highlight it by using setStyle() method
```

My problem is that I don't know the JS object where all the states are stored. Once I have that, I think the rest is just a matter of finding the right state and using `setStyle()`, like you see above in the highlight function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. They key is `map.eachLayer()` ([more info here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-eachlayer)).

```
    // highlight active state (in this case, arizona)
    // walk through all layers and find the states
    map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        var n = '';
        if (typeof layer.feature !== 'undefined') {
            var n = layer.feature.properties.name;
        }
        if (n.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase() == 'arizona') {
            // found the state-- go ahead and highlight it
            layer.setStyle({
                weight: 3,
                color: '#666',
                dashArray: '',
                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                fillColor:'#499bc4'
            });

            if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
                layer.bringToFront();
            }
        }           
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add a GeoJSON layer, you get to iterate over each feature, giving it its initial properties. Something along these lines:

```
L.geoJson(JSON.parse(data.geoData), {
                    style: function (feature) {
                        if ( feature.stateName === activeState ) {
                           return styleForActiveState;
                        } else {
                           return styleForNormalState;
                        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the example ([Leaflet US Map Example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html)), GeoJSON data is stored in file us-states.js.
In the example, the us-states.js in loaded into geojson variable, in this code:

```js
var geojson;// this is the variable you look for
geojson = L.geoJson(null, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

to find a layer by it's property is basically find a layer using it's layer id. So, during loading the geoJSON to geojson variable, you need to assign the geoJSON's feature id like this :

```js
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature
    });
    layer._leaflet_id = feature.id; //this is where you assign your custom id to it's layer.
}
```

after that you need to fire a 'click' event like this:

```js
function FindALayerByCustomId(layerId){
    var id = parseInt(layerId);
    var layer = geojson.getLayer(id); //find a layer using id
    layer.fireEvent('click');
}
```

Now, you could find a state you need using it's id.

```js
//State of Arizona has id of 4
FindALayerByCustomId(4);

//Or, you can place that in your document ready event,
$(document).ready(function () {
    //State of Arizona has id of 4
    FindALayerByCustomId(4);
});
```

No need to change anything on that example. Hopes it helps! (sorry for my poor English)